# Break columns only before specific list elements

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm using CSS columns to break a list in 3 columns.
It works fine but I have no control about the position of the break.
There are some titles in the list and I want to break only before them.
Is there a way to do that?

I tried to use `break-before: avoid`. But it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul .title {font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; margin: 20px 0 10px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try and avoid a break before the title, you can force a column break instead. Avoiding the break in part doesn't work because, technically, the browser *did* avoid a break there, by inserting the break earlier in the list.

Using `break-before: column` does the trick. However! Note that [browser support](https://caniuse.com/multicolumn) for this is lacking; for example, `column` will work in Chrome but not Firefox.

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul .title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    break-before: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li class="title">Title</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Now, all that said, I have a sneaky suspicion that *semantically* what you want is three distinct lists, each with a title, as opposed to one giant list. If that is true, then you can achieve near-full browser support with some restructuring and the use of flexbox.

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.outer-list {
    display: flex;
}
.outer-list > li {
    flex: 1;
}

ul .title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="outer-list">
    <li>
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below technique to fulfill your requirements.

```css
ul {
            padding-left: 0;
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
        }

        ul .title {
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
        .col {
            float: left;
            width: 33.33%;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row{
            display: inline-flex;
        }
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            /* display: inline-flex; */
            clear: both;
        }
```

```html
 <ul class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <li class="title">Title</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <li class="title">Title</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <li class="title">Title</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>

        </div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Be careful about the use of anything other than `li` as a direct child of `ul`; the W3C spec only allows `li`, `script`, and `template` as direct children: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element